# Scaling an Image Byte Array via Nearest Neighbor

Tags: c#, arrays, image, image-scaling, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to scale an image by using a byte array. My plan was to use the nearest neighbor to find the pixel data for the new byte array but I am having some issues transforming the source data of my image. srcImage is of type Image and I am able to successfully convert it to a byte array and convert it back into an image, I am having an issue with scaling that image using its byte array. I use a MemoryStream (in my byteArrayToImage method) to convert the trgData back to an Image but I receive an ArguementException telling me that the 'new MemoryStream(byteArray)' parameter is not valid.

Does anyone happen to know what might be the issue or how to correctly scale a byte array from an Image? For right now, we can assume that I am only scaling and saving png files but I would like to eventually expand this to other image formats.

Here is my code for the copying and scaling of the image data:

```
byte[] srcData = ImageToByteArraybyImageConverter(srcImage);

// data transformations here
//
float srcRatio = srcImage.Width / srcImage.Height;
int bitsPerPixel = ((int)srcImage.PixelFormat & 0xff00) >> 8;
int bytesPerPixel = (bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
int srcStride = 4 * ((srcImage.Width * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4);

// find max scale value
int scale = 3; // NOTE: temporary

// create new byte array to store new image
int width = srcImage.Width * scale;
int height = srcImage.Height * scale;
int stride = width;
byte[] trgData = new byte[height * stride];

// update the progress bar
progressBar1.Value = 10;

int i = -1; // index for src data
// copy pixel data 
for (int n = 0; n < trgData.Length; n++)
{
    if (n % stride == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    trgData[n] = srcData[i];
}

progressBar1.Value = 60;

// convert the pixel data to image
Image newImage = byteArrayToImage(trgData);
progressBar1.Value = 70;
if (newImage != null)
{
    // save the image to disk
    newImage.Save(newFileName);
    progressBar1.Value = 100;
}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions, and thank you!

Edited: Here are the methods that load and save the byte array

```
private byte[] ImageToByteArraybyImageConverter(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] imageByte = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
    return imageByte;
}


private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    Image returnImage = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    {
        returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: I think this will depend on how your function `ImageToByteArraybyImageConverter` is reading in the image. If its just opening an image file, then reading the bytes into an array, then the byte array is going to represent that image file format (.png, .gif, .jpg, etc)

Comment: Right now I am just using the ImageConverter class to convert an Image into a byte array. I don't really understand what other information I need to properly scale the image. I'll edit the question to display how I load and save the byte array

Comment: Quick observations: `srcImage.Width / srcImage.Height` is integer division; `srcStride` is unused.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the int division, and yea, I thought I might need those at some point but it never came to be.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a very strange thing here:

```
int i = -1; // index for src data
// copy pixel data 
for (int n = 0; n < trgData.Length; n++)
{
    if (n % stride == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    trgData[n] = srcData[i];
}
```

After every `width` iterations (because `stride == width`) you increment the original index. That is, the whole first line of the new image will be filled with first byte of the original image, the second line - with the second byte etc.

Try this instead:

```
int targetIdx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    int iUnscaled = i / scale;
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        int jUnscaled = j / scale;
        trgData[targetIdx++] = srcData[iUnscaled * origWidth + jUnscaled];
    }
}
```

Note that it assumes BPP=1, that is it copies evey byte `scale` times horizontally and vertically. It's not hard to modify it for BPP more than 1.

[Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/rTctxV) illustrating both algorithms (comment the first line to see how your algo behaves)

Comment: Thank you! I can see now that the copying of data was incorrect